# Perform calculations on tabulated results and print the results in tabulated form

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, tcl

I have a report which displays the clock periods along with the clock names and duty cycle.
Now, I would like to use `tcl` or `awk` or `perl` to make it display with clock period interms of freq and the duty cycle in percentage (%).
Which is the best way and how do I do it?

```
****************************************
Report : clock
Design : abc
Version: some version
Date   : xxx
****************************************

Attributes:
    p - Propagated clock
    G - Generated  clock
    I - Inactive   clock

Clock             Period          Waveform            Attrs     Sources
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
axi_ACLK          1.2500          {0.0000 0.6250}               {axi_ACLK}
xyz
                  1.2500          {0.0000 0.6250}     G         {abc/xyz}
```

I want the output displayed something like this(please note that xyz period is on the next line):

```
Clock             Period          Waveform            Attrs     Sources
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

axi_ACLK          800          50%               {axi_ACLK}
xyz
                  800          50%    G         {abc/xyz}
```

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: what have you tried ? awk can easily go line by line and do mathematical operations on columns. What is not working in your case ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there really this line break in the second clock specification?

Comment: Update: 1) I could get rid of rid of the line break. 2) When I try awk: I get an error:
 awk '{print $1,1/$2}' new.rpt
awk: (FILENAME=new.rpt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: Please number the input and output, by running them through `cat -net`.

Comment: And are you assuming `ns` as the units of time? The Prime Time should put that in the report file.

Comment: Yes it is ns and I don't see PT adding the unit.

Comment: Are all clocks have their period and On time on the next line (like for xyz clk)?  You didn't number the lines.

Comment: no now I have reported such that all the periods are reported in the same line and next to the clock name. What is the intention behind numbering the lines?

Comment: Then why that comment that xyz period on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep, GNU awk, I whipped up a rudimentary and quick n dirty solution to your problem. Assuming there are no empty lines after the all dashes line and the clock reporting always happens after the all dashes line and there is only one such line.

Also the periods are in ns as discussed in the comments.

```
$ pt_rpt="your_primetime_report_name";

$ fws="$(< "$pt_rpt" grep -m1 -B1 -E '^-+$' | head -n1 | grep -oP '\S+(?:\s+|$)' | awk '{print length()}' | paste -s)" \
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = ENVIRON["fws"]
    OFS = ""
  }
  /^-+$/,0 {
    if ( /^-+$/ ) { print prev }
    else {
      ### frequency calculation
      Tper = $2+0
      freq = sprintf("%-*s", length($2), sprintf("%g", 1e3/Tper))
      $2 = freq
      ### duty cycle determination
      Ton = $3; sub(/[[:space:]]+$/, "", Ton)
      nf = split(Ton, a, /[}[:space:]]/)
      Ton = a[nf-1]
      D = sprintf("%-*s", length($3), sprintf("%g%%", 1e2*Ton/Tper))
      $3 = D
    }
    print; next
  }
  { prev = $0 }
'  < "$pt_rpt"
```

**Output**:

```
Clock             Period          Waveform            Attrs     Sources
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
axi_ACLK          800             50%                           {axi_AC
xyz               800             50%                 G         {abc/xy
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your efforts! Can you also please tell me how do I invoke this? Sorry but I have never used GNU. Meanwhile I could do it in tcl in DC/PT as well.

Comment: Doing it within dcshell/primetime is the best and most robust. Doing it any other way will always be flaky. YMMV.

Comment: Agree. But sometimes when you receive the reports from somebody else and you want to quickly analyze, this serves handy.